# Greenfoot: Jfilechooser crashes program

Tags: java, swing, debugging, jfilechooser, greenfoot

So I am writing a program for a high school project in Java using Greenfoot. In my program, I use a JFileChooser to let the user choose an image to edit it and etc.

Anyways, it seems that the JFileChooser always crashes my JVM when I run it a second time. It always works when I first start the program, but if I don't restart the JVM and the program, it will freeze my program the second time I use it.

I'm not sure if this is some sort of bug or bad coding practice (maybe not properly disposing of swing elements?)

Essentially, this is what I use to open the JFileChooser:

```
final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
fc.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("Images", "jpg", "png"));
int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(frame); //freezes here
if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    //etc...
```

If it makes a difference, I am using a mac with Java 1.7.0_71

Any help is appreciated - thanks!

Comment: You'll need to provide a runnable example which demonstrates your problem

Comment: When Java "freezes", take a thread dump and see what is happening. The JDK ship with a bunch of tools allowing to take a thread dump (like e.g. `jstack`) and if you are running from an IDE, the IDE allows to take a thread dump as well

Comment: Ok, I took a thread dump and noticed this:  http://justpaste.it/no7m

Answer (score 0):

Greenfoot runs your code on a particular thread (internally called the simulation thread).  If you want to use Swing, you must use it from the Swing thread.  I believe your code has deadlocked because of using Swing classes from off the Swing thread.  You can use EventQueue.invokeLater to switch to the Swing thread and back (Greenfoot isn't designed to support this, but it should work anyway -- invokeLater is a better bet than invokeAndWait).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply! Can you explain more in detail how I would use EventQueue.invokeLater()? I'm not sure how to use this. Like, what would I put as the argument?